# Difference between "time" and "timing"?

Tags: grammar, usage

I want to ask regarding the time at which I will be interviewed. Which option is correct? Or both are incorrect? I am confused regarding the usage of "time" and "timing"?

1. What is the timing of the interview on Monday?
2. What is the time of the interview on Monday?

Comment: Intuitively, "time" would mean simply what time does it start, and "timing" would suggest you want a schedule (what time does it start and end and if it's divided into sections what time do each of them start and end). But dictionary definitions don't really support this distinction.

Comment: In your context, "timing" would probably be an undesirable "affectation". If you don't have a clear idea of *why* you might want to use it, stick with asking "what time".

Comment: It would sound more idiomatic to say  "What time is the interview", not "*What is the time of the interview."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, "what is the time" is preferred if you want to know the time the interview starts.

Timing is often used in similar concepts; but they way it is used differs.

- Timing can be used to describe a time within a repeating period.  For example, a timing chain (part of a car) is used to make sure the engine performs operations in the correct order for each revolution of the crankshaft.
- Timing  can be used to describe relationships between items, or to describe those relationships in a general manner.  The timing of the events is critical.  The timing of the play will follow the announcement by the Master of Ceremonies.

Timing is rarely used in good speech to specify an exact time; but, many people use the word timing in less-than-good speech.  So, if you used timing, keep in mind that you might get a response like "sometime Wednesday" or "after we get ten candidates to interview".  When you use time, you will more likely get a response like "3 PM Wednesday the 28th".

Comment: And while "What is the time of the interview" is perfectly acceptable, as others have mentioned "What time is the interview" works equally well.  Many people prefer short sentences and short descriptions in a work setting; but, both are equally correct.  (Some of our great English writers preferred long sentences).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, It is a great help for me.

Comment: @JohnSmith Glad to help